# Bounding $|\cos (2n+1)\theta |$

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to find a bound for $|\cos (2n+1)\theta |$ by something of the form $c(n)|\cos \theta|$. I am suspecting that we can bound it by $(2n+1)|\cos \theta|$ but I'm not sure how to show that this is true.

Comment: Could you tell us why you want to have a bound like this? At first this bound looks useless as it is an overkill of a bound.

Comment: @MrYouMath I want something along the lines of $|\cos (2n+1)\theta|\leq c(n)|\cos \theta|$. A linear bound dependent on n is enough for my needs and I don't think it can get better than $c(n)=2n+1$ so it's definitely not overkill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use $2\cos t=e^{it}+e^{-it}$.
Then
$$\frac{\cos(2n+1)t}{\cos t}=\frac{e^{(2n+1)it}+e^{-(2n+1)it}}{e^{it}+e^{-it}}=e^{2nit}-e^{2(n-1)t}+e^{2(n-2)it}-\cdots+e^{-2nit}.$$
As each of these exponentials is bounded by $1$ is absolute value,
you get
$$|\cos(2n+1)t|\le(2n+1)|\cos t|.$$
This is the best possible; take $t$ close to $\pi/2$, then $e^{-2it}$ is close to $-1$ etc.

Comment: @PeterSzilas You did see the factor $|\cos(t)|$, didn't you?

Comment: Thank you! I did not think to expand it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Well since $\cos(0)=1$ I'm not sure you can do better than $c(n)=1$. (although you can bound $\sin n\theta$ or complex $\cos n\theta$ non-trivially)

Comment: $c(n)$ obviously cannot be $1$. Take $\cos (\frac{\pi}{3})$ with $n=3$ as an example.